# If $f$ is an integrable function on $[0, \infty)$, does $f$ have an antiderivative?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, continuity, solution-verification

I am not sure about continuity of an integrable function after integration.

Let's assume, $f$ is integrable at $[0, \infty)$. Then let $F$ be the antiderivative of $f$:

$$\int f(x)dx = F(x)$$

Now the integration being defined and real, means that $F$ is differentiable at $[0, \infty)$, we are given the anti derivative

$$\frac{dF}{dx} = f(x)$$

$$dF = f(x)dx = 0 \\ \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\Delta F(x) = 0$$

Therefore it is continuous at $[0, \infty)$, I can say for example directly that

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}F(x) = F(0)$$

And in a side note I know that continuity implies the limit at point $x$ from the left and right ($x+0, x-0$)

Comment: I am pretty sure I proved the case

Comment: I'm afraid the write up you provide is not very clear. Your comment "where $f$ is the derivative of $F$" makes it unclear whether you define $f$ or $F$ to be the differentiable function (see Son Gohan's answer for why that is relevant). If you mean to define $F$ in terms of $f$, then the $f$ is the derivative of $F$, but you have to prove that, so it's confusing to see it stated like that at the beginning. If you have assumed that the integral of a differentiable function is itself differentiable (which is true), then $F$ being differentiable implies $F$ is continuous.

Comment: The notation $F(x) = \int f(x)\, dx$ is also undesirable - there are many indefinite integrals of a function, so to assign one of them to a variable is not well-defined. The conclusions you draw are true of every such function, but you do not make that clear.

Comment: I write it here since my post was more a comment than an answer: Note that as it is formulated right now, if $f$ is differentiable, it is not necessary Riemann integrable. Please see here the Volterra function here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function Indeed a continuous function on, say, the real line need not be riemann integrable.

Comment: @preferred_anon, Son Gohan oh right sorry, I got distracted I made a misspelling just that, I corrected

Comment: I think you're looking for [the first Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part). If $f$ is merely integrable, then the Riemann integral might not be differentiable, and if it is differentiable, then the derivative might not equal $f$. If $f$ is continuous however, its antiderivatives are all continuous, and differentiable, and all their derivatives equal $f$.

Comment: @preferred_anon You are wrong,   $\frac{d\int f(x)dx}{dx} = f(x)$ is a property that holds for $F$ being the antiderivative of $f$, and another property $d\int f(x)dx = f(x)dx$

Comment: @SubGenius Consider the function which is constantly $0$ except at $x=0$, where it takes the value $1$. I encourage you to read a proof of FTC and see where it fails in this case.

Comment: @preferred_anon $F(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$ which exists, and $f$ is integrable at $[0, \infty)$, therefore that implies $\frac{dF}{dx} = f(x)$ i.e $\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\Delta f(x) = 0 = f(x)df$

Comment: @SubGenius i'm sorry, it just doesn't. If you would like a detailed explanation of why the FTC's assumptions are necessary, I encourage you to open a new question. The content in your question body does not really constitute a proof, or a clear statement to be proved, so it's hard to evaluate its correctness or suggest an alternative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120552/discussion-between-subgenius-and-preferred-anon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a detailed discussion in chat about this question. There was some confusion about the relationship between the antiderivative of a function, and the integrability of the function.

First of all, note that [the fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) says that if $f$ is a continuous function, then the definite integral $$F(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(t)\, dt$$
satisfies $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$. We call a function $F$ with this property an *antiderivative* of $f$.

Not all integrable functions are continuous. The confusion in the OP was about the antiderivative of $f$ in this situation. It turns out that merely integrable functions might not have an antiderivative.

Consider, for example, the function $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x=0\\0 & x \ne 0\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ is a Riemann integrable function. In fact,

$$F(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(t)\, dt = 0$$

for all $x$. So $F'(x) = 0$ for all $x$, meaning that the definite integral is *not* an antiderivative of $f$. In fact, there is no differentiable function $F$ with $F'(x) = f(x)$ for every $x$. To see this, note that if there were such an antiderivative, it would have to be constant on $(0, \infty)$ (because the derivative is 0 there). But then, because it's continuous, it has to have $F(0)$ be the same constant - meaning that $F'(0) = 0 \ne f(0)$.

To come back to the original point: If $f$ *has* an antiderivative $F$, then $F$ is differentiable by definition, so it is continuous too. But if $f$ is integrable, it might not have an antiderivative.